# How can i filter by an other object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array

How can i *filter* the results of an array based on an object in `ng-repeat`. The object i want to filter by looks like this:

```js
{
    [
    'gender': 'male',
    'languages': ['German', 'English'],
    'country': 'Marocco'
    ],
    [
    'gender': 'female',
    'languages': ['German', 'French'],
    'country': 'Kosovo'
    ]
} 
| filter:{'languages': ['Urdu', 'French'], 'country': ['Kosovo']}
```

Results in:

```
[
'gender': 'female',
'languages': ['German', 'French'],
'country': 'Kosovo'
]
```

Comment: I don't see any multidimensional array. Its an object and properties of objects holds array

Comment: just updated my question, sorry! I guess it was a bit confusing.

Comment: `{'German', 'French'},` is not an array. change it to you `['German', 'French']`

Answer (score -1):

For instance, selecting all of the words that have the letter e in them, we could run our filter like so:

```
{{ ['Ari', 'Lerner', 'Likes', 'To', 'Eat', 'Pizza'] | filter:'e' }}
<!-- ["Lerner","Likes","Eat"] -->
```

If we want to filter on objects, we can use the the object filter notation. For instance, if we have an array of people objects with a list of their favorite foods, we could filter them like so:

```
{{ [{
'name': 'Ari',
'City': 'San Francisco',
'favorite food': 'Pizza'
}, {
'name': 'Nate',
'City': 'San Francisco',
'favorite food': 'indian food'
}] | filter:{'favorite food': 'Pizza'} }}

<!-- [{"name":"Ari","City":"San Francisco","favorite food":"Pizza"}] -->
```

We can also filter based on a function that we define (in this example, on the containing $scope
object):

Comment: the object is not the one i want to filter, but i want an array based on that object.